# Is using InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider correct way to connect to AWS S3 from Ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Until my code works, I have set bucket policy too wide open.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy15",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bcktName",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bcktName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using Elastic BeanStalk which in turn uses AWS Ec2. 
The Ec2 instance has aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role which was provided FullAccess to S3 (I understand full access is dangerous).

I'm using the following java code in my webapp which is deployed to Ec2.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                  .withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))
                  .build();
              versionId = s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", name, convFile))
                  .getVersionId();
```

1) Is this the correct way to connect to S3 from Ec2 in a java code?
2) [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) documentation confuses me as I'm not sure if I have to set up Environment variables and/or Java system properties and/or The default credential profiles file and/or Amazon ECS container credentials and/or Instance profile credentials ?

Please help me. I'm struck with this issue for almost a week.

PS: 
Following is the ec2InstanceRole assigned to my profile

```
Role ARN  arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
Role description  
Instance Profile ARNs  arn:aws:iam::111111111111:instance-profile/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
Path   /
Creation time  2017-10-17 11:27 PDT
```

And the policies assigned to above role are

```
  AmazonS3FullAccess
  AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
  AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
  AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your code should work as is, you can remove this part all together: `.withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(false))` The AWS SDK for Java will automatically pick up the instance profile if you don't specify any credential settings. You can just do this:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
```

If that doesn't work, try removing the bucket policy from the S3 bucket completely. You don't need the bucket policy in order to allow the server using the IAM instance profile to access the bucket, and if you have a typo or something in your bucket policy it could be breaking things.

If that doesn't work, add the IAM policy assigned to the IAM instance profile to your question.

Comment: I tried AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build(); with both my existing bucket policy as well as removing my bucket policy. No luck.

Comment: I have added the IAM policy assigned to the role which was in turn assigned to Ec2 instance in Quesiton.

Comment: Btw, Do I need to set Environment variables and/or Java system properties and/or The default credential profiles in Ec2 instance when Ec2InstanceRole is assigned to Ec2 instance?

Comment: No, quite the opposite. You need to make sure you don't have an AWS credentials file on the system, and you need to make sure you don't have any credentials defined in environment variables. If you have either of those things it will override the instance profile credentials. I recommend reading this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: That page is super confusing. Following are my confusions
1) The document says the chain looks for keys in the said order. So should I set up env variables, java system variables in Ec2 instance?(This contradicts to your above comment)
2) As per this link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html?shortFooter=true  , Should I set up env variables etc. "If your application creates an AWS client using the default constructor, then the client will search for credentials using the default credentials provider chain, in the following order:"

Comment: It will look for environment variables first, if it doesn't find them it will look for java system properties next, if it doesn't find system properties it will look for a credentials file next, etc. Since you want to use option 5, EC2 instance profiles, you need to make sure you aren't doing any of those other things, so that it will fall through the provider chain and get to the point that it checks for and uses the instance profile you have configured.

Comment: Got it. Deleting my instances and creating things from fresh. Could you answer this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996536/should-i-use-ec2-or-elasticbeanstalk-when-i-am-creating-a-new-role-where-my-ec2